# Swixml xml files to bundled inside jar

Tags: java, embedded-resource, swixml

I am using swixml to create the UI from xml files. When I run the program using eclipse it runs fine. However when I make a jar of it, swixml throws a file not found type exception. If however, I store the xml outside the jar and in the same directory, it miraculously works. I am at a bit of loss as to how to get this to work.

I use sax builder to read the xml. The views go in a directory views/ in the jar. I verified that the directory structure is indeed present in the generated jar.

Comment: Does 'sax builder' accept URLs?  This is an [tag:embedded-resource] that should be accessed by URL.

Comment: I am not sure actually. I'll check it out